# Canvas bouncing ball randomly passes left border

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a canvas background with randomly moving balls. Balls will bounce when they reach the edge. It should be easy but apparently I missed something.

Right now, it looks pretty good for the first few second, but after a while, these balls just wouldn't bother to pass the left border, and never bounce back. I've been trying to figure out for days, and failed. Any help is appreciated.

```
update(delta, canvas) {

    let deltaX = delta * Math.cos(this.movingDirection * Math.PI / 180);
    let deltaY = delta * Math.sin(this.movingDirection * Math.PI / 180);

    this.axisX += deltaX;
    this.axisY += deltaY;

    //set border
    if (this.axisX > (canvas.width)) {
        if (this.movingDirection > 270 && this.movingDirection < 360) {
            this.movingDirection = 180 + this.movingDirection;
        } else if (this.movingDirection < 90 && this.movingDirection > 0) {
                this.movingDirection = 180 - this.movingDirection;
        }
    }
    if (this.axisX < 0) {
        if (this.movingDirection > 180 && this.movingDirection < 270) {
            this.movingDirection = 540 - this.movingDirection;
        } else if (this.movingDirection <= 180 && this.movingDirection > 90) {
            this.movingDirection = 180 - this.movingDirection;
        }
    }

    if (this.axisY > (canvas.height) || this.axisY < 0) {
        if (this.movingDirection > 180 ) {
            this.movingDirection = 360 - this.movingDirection;
        } else if (this.movingDirection <= 180) {
            this.movingDirection = 360 - this.movingDirection;
        }
    }
    this.draw();
}
```

this.movingDirection is a randomly generated number between 0 and 360.

Here is a complete example https://jsfiddle.net/calmdown/qr89b034/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to try and find out what is wrong with the code as your method is way out there (To complicated)

Rather you can use the delta x and y to do the wall bounce and from that calculate the new direction.

The following `update` function will fix your problem.

```
update(delta, canvas) {
    var dx, dy,x,y;
    dx = delta * Math.cos(this.movingDirection * Math.PI / 180);
    dy = delta * Math.sin(this.movingDirection * Math.PI / 180);
    x = this.axisX += dx;
    y = this.axisY += dy;
    const r = this.radius;


    if(dx > 0) { // moving to the right
        if(x + r >= canvas.width) {
            x = canvas.width - r;
            dx = -dx;
        }    
    }else if(dx < 0) { // moving to the left
        if(x - r <= 0) {
            x = r;
            dx = -dx;
        }       
    }
    if(dy > 0) { // moving down
        if(y + r >= canvas.height) {
            y = canvas.height - r;
            dy = -dy;
        }        
    }else if(dy < 0) { // moving up
        if(y - r <= 0) {
            y = r;
            dy = -dy;
        }           
    }

    this.axisX = x;
    this.axisY = y;
    this.movingDirection = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (180 / Math.PI);

    this.draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @blindman67 ! This opens a new way for me to look at this problem. I'll try tonight.